# This query does not support recovering from checkpoint location. Delete checkpoint/testmemeory/offsets to start over

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I have created In-Memory tables inside Spark and try to restart the Spark structured streaming job after failure. It gets "This query does not support recovering from checkpoint location. Delete checkpoint/TEST_IN_MEMORY/offsets to start over."

What is the Concept of Checkpoint In-Memory sink? Is there any way to rectify it? (can we delete the old and the new checkpoint dynamically?)

I am using Data Stax 5.1.6 clusters, so I don't have Choice I have to go with Spark 2.0.2 version only.

```
val kafkaDataFrame_inmemory = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "Localhost:9092")
  .option("subscribe", "TEST_IN_MOEMORY")
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
  .load()


val checkpoint =  "C/Users/756661/Desktop/KT DOCS/spark/In_MEM_TABLE"+ UUID.randomUUID.toString

kafkaDataFrame_inmemory
  .writeStream
  .format("memory")
  .option("truncate", false)
  .queryName("IN_MEM_TABLE")
  .outputMode("update")
  .option("checkpointLocation",checkpoint)
  .start()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simply remove the line `.option("checkpointLocation",checkpoint)` from your code and start over.

Per the error message, the memory data source does not support recovering from checkpoint location. Any attempt at (re)starting a streaming query that uses `memory` format with a directory that exists already will fail.

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: This query does not support recovering from checkpoint location. Delete xxx/offsets to start over.;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager.createQuery(StreamingQueryManager.scala:240)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager.startQuery(StreamingQueryManager.scala:326)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.start(DataStreamWriter.scala:267)
  ... 49 elided
```

It's not to say that memory data source won't use a checkpoint directory. It will, but it is going to be of the name randomly generated.

---

> can we delete the old and the new checkpoint dynamically?

Sure and that's the only way to start the streaming query.